# How to convert time values inside jinja code to the browser's local timezone when the page loads?

Tags: javascript, python, flask, jinja2, momentjs

I have a list of flask generated time values in this format: YYYY-DD-MM hh:mm:ss. These time values work as url links and are displayed in my html file using jinja2 like so:

```
{% for job in jobs %}
    <a href=”{{ url_for(‘jobs/by_id’,job_id=job.job_id) }}">
    {{ job.finishtime }}              #this is the time value
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

I want these time values to be automatically converted to the browser's local timezone. I tried using the flask-moment extension but after following all instructions and using `{{ moment(job.finishtime).format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a') }}`, the time disapppers from the html page when I load it. I tried other moment functions as well but keep getting errors.

Is there a better way to make moment.js talk to my jinja code?

I was hoping not to have to deal with python datetime.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, Jinja2 is rendered on the server, so it's code doesn't ever run on the client's machine - it can't (easily) get hold of the timezone.
This means that Javascript is run *after* the Jinja2 template is rendered, so you can't use JS within jinja2 tags.

There are a few ways to get around this/solve your problem:

1) When the user first visits your site (or logs in, if that's possible), have some javascript set a `timezone` cookie. This can then be read serverside, and passed into the template - something like this:

```
# On the server
def view_jobs_page(request, response):
    import datetime
    tz = datetime.timedelta(seconds = int(request.cookies["timezone"])) # Pass this into the Jinja2 render function
    # ... Do stuff


# In your template
local time: {{ job.finishtime + tz }}
```

It's hard to give a more detailed example without knowing the exact stack and code structure that you're using. This also has the downside of using `datetime`, which you didn't want.

2) Use javascript to apply the timedelta:

```
<!-- In the head -->
<script>
// When the page loads - the Jinja template is already rendered now
window.onload = function() {
  // Get all the elements with the given class, and map through them
  document.querySelectorAll(".datetime_to_be_adjusted").forEach(function(el){
    var utcTime = moment.utc(el.innerText);  // This is the time in UTC
    utcTime.local();  // Switch to using the browser's local timezone
    el.innerText = utcTime.format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');  // Write the local time back to the element
  });
}
</script>
...
{% for job in jobs %}
    <a href=”{{ url_for(‘jobs/by_id’,job_id=job.job_id) }}" class="datetime_to_be_adjusted">
        {{ job.finishtime }}
    </a>
{% endfor %}
```

This of course relies of momentJS being included in the page, and uses it's [UTC parsing mechanis](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/utc/).

Comment: Had an error trying to use the Js part, had to change to this: ```let dates = document.querySelectorAll(".datetime_to_be_adjusted");
  dates.forEach(function(el) {
    let utcTime = moment.utc(el.innerText);  // This is the time in UTC
    utcTime.local();  // Switch to using the browser's local timezone
    el.innerText = utcTime.format('MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a');  // Write the local time back to the element
  });```